# SSHD config: PermitUserEnvironment on a case-by-case basis

Tags: git, sshd

I have a git server where people set up remote repositories over ssh, and there's a git user that they all connect as which has secure permissions and whatnot.

I'm editing the pre-receive hook in a repo so that it sees if the environment variable, `$GIT_USER`, matches the list of allowed users for that repo to prevent unauthorized users from pushing.

This environment variable is set individually in the git user's `.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

However, I don't want environment variables to be set for ssh for any user besides git.

Is there any way to edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` such that `PermitUserEnvironment` is only enabled for the git user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set "PermitUserEnvironment no" and at the bottom of sshd_config you can override settings on a per-user basis:

```
Match User git
    PermitUserEnvironment yes
```

That should accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 3):

The workaround would be to:

- keep `PermitUserEnvironment`  to 'no'
- replace `/usr/local/bin/git` by a wrapper script which would:

  - set the relevant environment variables
  - call the actual `git` binary.